# How do I add liquidity to my token so I can swap it for ethereum?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I'm making a solidity smart contract for ethereum and I want to be able to have users swap my token for ethereum. In order to do this I need liquidity to be added to my token so users can swap. My code so far is:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";

contract YourToken is ERC20, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapRouter;
    address public uniswapPair;

    event TokensSwappedAndLiquidityAdded(uint256 inputAmount, uint256 outputAmount, uint256 liquidityTokens);
    event TokensMinted(address indexed account, uint256 amount);

    constructor(address _uniswapRouter) ERC20("Infuraa Token", "INXT") Ownable(msg.sender) {
        uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uniswapRouter);
        uniswapPair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapRouter.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapRouter.WETH());
        _mint(msg.sender, 980 * 10**12 * 10**18);
    }

    // Function to swap tokens for ETH and add liquidity
    function swapTokensForEthAndAddLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount) external nonReentrant {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= tokenAmount, "Insufficient balance");

        // Approve the router to spend the tokens
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapRouter), tokenAmount);

        // Perform the swap
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapRouter.WETH();

        uint256 initialEthBalance = address(this).balance;

        uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForETH(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            msg.sender,
            block.timestamp
        );

        uint256 ethOutput = address(this).balance - initialEthBalance;

        // Add liquidity
 uint256 slippageAmount = tokenAmount * 5 / 100;  // 5% slippage
uniswapRouter.addLiquidityETH{value: ethOutput}(
    address(this),
    tokenAmount,
    tokenAmount - slippageAmount,  // minimum amount of token liquidity
    ethOutput - slippageAmount,   // minimum amount of ETH liquidity
    msg.sender,
    block.timestamp
);


        emit TokensSwappedAndLiquidityAdded(tokenAmount, ethOutput, 0);
    }

    // Function to set the Uniswap router address (in case it needs to be updated)
   function setUniswapRouter(address _uniswapRouter) external onlyOwner {
    uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_uniswapRouter);

    // Check if the pair already exists
    address pair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapRouter.factory()).getPair(address(this), uniswapRouter.WETH());
    if (pair == address(0)) {
        // Pair does not exist, create it
        uniswapPair = IUniswapV2Factory(uniswapRouter.factory()).createPair(address(this), uniswapRouter.WETH());
    } else {
        // Pair already exists, use the existing pair
        uniswapPair = pair;
    }
}


    // Function to mint additional tokens, only callable by the owner
    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        _mint(account, amount);
        emit TokensMinted(account, amount);
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

When I try to run the "swapTokensForEthAndAddLiquidity" in Remix, it gives me an error that says:

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract.

and then the console says insufficient liquidity. How do I add liquidity properly to my code so users can swap my token for ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to go into why you are interacting with uniswap from within your smart contract as I supposed its out of scope here, but the problem is that you are trying to swap `uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForETH(` before you add any liquidity `uniswapRouter.addLiquidityETH{value: ethOutput}(`.